# c++: initialising an object of a class in another class

Tags: c++, initialization

Could not find a clear solution for this problem.

I have two classes `Point` and `Vector`. `Vector` is a child of `Point` In one of the methods of class `Point` I want to use an object of class `Vector`. I do it like this:

```
class Point
{
    double x, y, z;

    public:
    // constructor from 3 values
    Point(double x, double y, double z)
    : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}

    // method move point
    Point move(Vector vect, double dist)
    {
        Vector vectU = vect.unit();
        return sum(vectU.multiplyScalar(dist));
    }
};

class Vector: public Point
{
    double x, y, z;

    public:
    // constructor from 3 values
    Vector(double x, double y, double z)
    : Point(x, y, z), x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}

    // create unit vector
    Vector unit()
    {
        double len = length();
        return Vector(x / len, y / len, z / len);
    }
};
```

When I compile this it gives me an error in line `Point move(Vector vect, double dist)` `"Vector" has not been declared`. I cannot find any useful answer for this error. How do I do this initialisation?

Comment: Does it really make sense for `Vector` to inherit from `Point`? It may be simpler to have de-coupled classes.

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought it would be better if I do not duplicate methods of `Point` in `Vector`.

Comment: You may should erase points completly, since it is basically a vector.

Comment: @juanchopanza I have to disagree. Classes are created to make abstractions of real objects. In maths, point is practically equivalent with vector, so deriving vector from point makes perfect sense. Also, moving point by a vector seems to be a good idea too. I'd look into this specific matter rather than stick to general rules.

Comment: @xeed Yes, but I want to clearly differentiate one from another.

Comment: @Spook Sorry, but I can't see a vector as a point, despite the similarities. I have implemented 3D geometries before and never had to use this kind of inheritance relationship.

Comment: @Spook In any case, the move would make more sense as a non-member `Point operator+(Vector, Point)`

Comment: @juanchopanza I studied maths and on linear algebra terms "point" and "vector" were interchanged. What I want to say is that we cannot judge whether to follow this guideline or not without knowing the problem and environment OP uses. It's like saying, that multi-inheritance is *always* bad.

Comment: Alright, here a quite simple solution, without knowing what comes next in the Vector class. Derive Point from Vector. It does make more sense and it solves your issue for now :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Well yeah, but these are only semantics. Where does OP put the appropriate method is his choice.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help.

Comment: Oh cmon. Comment on my smartass comment

Comment: @xeed :) from my point of view `Point` is the most basic geometrical object which defines all other objects like Vectors, Lines etc. So, I like the idea that Vectors, Lines and others inherit the methods of Point. But I am going to try your way also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ a class needs to be declared before it is defined.  In your example with everything in one file, it has no idea what a `Vector` is when you define your `Point::move` function.

Typically, we'd have a header file per class (`MyClass.h` etc) and put the function definitions in a cpp file per class (`MyClass.cpp`)

So you need to restructure to something like:

**Point.h:**

```
#ifndef _POINT_H
#define _POINT_H

class Vector;  // Forward declaration so you don't need to include Vector.h here

class Point
{
    double x, y, z;

    public:
    // constructor from 3 values
    Point(double x, double y, double z);

    // method move point
    Point move(Vector vect, double dist);
}

#endif // _POINT_H
```

**Point.cpp**

```
#include "Point.h"
#include "Vector.h"

// constructor from 3 values
Point::Point(double x, double y, double z)
: x(x), y(y), z(z)
{}

// method move point
Point Point::move(Vector vect, double dist)
{
    Vector vectU = vect.unit();
    return sum(vectU.multiplyScalar(dist));
}
```

**Vector.h**

```
#ifndef _VECTOR_H
#define _VECTOR_H

#include "Point.h"

class Vector: public Point
{
    double x, y, z;

    public:
    // constructor from 3 values
    Vector(double x, double y, double z)
    : Point(x, y, z), x(x), y(y), z(z);

    // create unit vector
    Vector unit();
}

#endif // _VECTOR_H
```

**Vector.cpp**

```
#include "Vector.h"

// constructor from 3 values
Vector::Vector(double x, double y, double z)
: Point(x, y, z), x(x), y(y), z(z)
{}

// create unit vector
Vector Vector::unit()
{
    double len = length();
    return Vector(x / len, y / len, z / len);
}
```

(disclaimer, No guarantees that this will compile and work straight away, this is just to demonstrate how the code should be split up!)

Comment: do I need to put all my methods in `*.h` and then describe them in `*.cpp`?

Comment: Yes, unlike C# or Java where it's all defined in a single file.   You don't *have* to do it this way, but it makes it much simpler to manage if you do!

Comment: I assume in `Vector.h` the `unit` method must look like `Vector unit();`

Comment: Also I'd forgotten to remove the body from the `Vector` constructor - which, in the case of an empty body, is perfectly fine to leave in the .h file like that, but for consistency I've removed it.  (If you did leave it in the .h, you wouldn't need to define it in the .cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Put a forward declaration:

```
class Vector;
```

at the beginning of the file.

Also, put a ; after the definition of each class.

Comment: That won't work in this case. The complete type is needed. But that can be fixed by moving the `move` implementation out of the `Point` class definition.

Comment: it says `"vect" has incomplete type`

Comment: @juanchopanza: Can it really? Even with the argument passed in by-value? I don't think so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, I had missed that. What I said, plus "pass the `Vector` by (const) reference".

Answer (score 0):

If your class `Vector`

```
class Vector: public Point
```

inherits from `Point`, then you should not be using `Vector` in the base class `Point` (the base class shouldn't know anything about the derived class).

Also you are redefining `x, y, z` in your derived class `Vector`, which defeats the point of inheritance and can lead to very nasty behaviour when using polymorphism.

Comment: You should re-write (re-think) your code so that the point class does not need the Vector class. If you want to move a point using a vector you can write a standalone function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual function may  do the trick for you.
ie 
move() Stub in the base 
move() declaration in the derived.
Use pointers for dynamic binding.

eg point *x = new vector(...)
x.move()

etc etc.